# I want to use Twitter API using Bluemix and then store the data into dashDB

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, ibm-cloud

I want to use Twitter API using Bluemix and then store the data into dashDB,  which is also a service of Bluemix.

Both services Twitter API and dashDB database are given by Bluemix, but I don't know how to store data from Twitter into dashDB.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to look at the dashDB Learning Center, in particular the tutorial below that explains how to load Twitter data into dashDB:

https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/dashdb/get/load-twitter-data-into-dashdb/

The sample code is available in this [link](https://hub.jazz.net/project/torsstei/Twitter-Loader?cm_mc_uid=33054902895514473371087&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1447732549).

More specifically this file from above link:

```
src/example/jpa/LoadResource.java
```

Contains code that will load Twitter data into dashDB.

Comment: But sir I want to kno how can I link my database manually to twitter api ...so that I can control which field is going to store in my database.. Will u plz giv me step by step description